# How to work similar colours of an image using Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, images, image-editing

I want to enlarge both sides of my image with similar colors of my image by adding sth(i dont know it) without damaging the quality.

More clearly, i have an image(.gif format) 1100x400 resolution and it contains lots of mixed colors. i want to make it 1350x400 resolution.When I change it by hand, its quality reduces a lot.Instead, I would like to add columns(by similar colour filled areas of my image) to each side of my photo.I want to add an object 125px through left side and right side for enlarging the image(as medium or high quality).

How can I achieve this with Inkscape?

Actually, can I achieve this with Inkscape? :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why Inkscape?  Doesn't really sound like a job for a vector program...

Comment: I have used for svg export Inkscape.Because of that i was trying to create with Inkscape on this problem.So, Can I achieve this with Photoshop?

Comment: What you might be able to do is recreate the image in Inkscape, but without seeing it, I can't tell you much more.  Inkscape might not be the right software - can you post an example image?

Comment: https://3.downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/48da862e948e56a266ab02f100b9e1c1e806a843f1e94c05f2affba23f153337/599c5f7e/DFUz2abLBZSP7TTcf0t1YjYIEHTC8lG4p0FLsLPHhbneoeDsWEl_b1ZU0ai_oYzqxS7bEiKRM3EauwgQOC3XYw%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=newversion4%20-%20Kopya.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&fsize=612000&hid=1dab52a37dd75890e955599d94334b3a&media_type=image&tknv=v2&etag=f7bd3633919d7354b49328129d8bf904

There are two white columns in two sides of photo.How to fill this white columns in a similar colors of photo.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the size (it's not really the resolution) of an svg file you're exporting from inkscape, then that's the place to work on it as you first suspected.

The `Document properties` options (from the `File` menu or `ctrl+shift+D`) are what you need.

[image: document properties]

When you change the page size you'll see that the empty space is added on the right.  What I find easiest at that point is to group everything (I'm assuming a single layer here for simplicity) and centre that group with respect to the page (grouping isn't strictly necessary -- see the option just below the box I've highlighted):

[image: recentre]